# jQuery datatables columnDefs issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Why isn't jQuery datatables `columnDefs` working with class names? The `render` callback is never fired.

The [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) states:

> A string - class name will be matched on the TH for the column

Also, if I change to target index `[0]` instead, I get an error. Also, it fires about 22 times. Shouldn't it fire 6 times? 1 for each cell with index 0?

```
var dataSet = [
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 4.0','Win 95+','4','X'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.0','Win 95+','5','C'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.5','Win 95+','5.5','A'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 6','Win 98+','6','A'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 7','Win XP SP2+','7','A'],
    ['Trident','AOL browser (AOL desktop)','Win XP','6','A']
];

$('#example').dataTable( {

    columnDefs: [
        {
            render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                console.log(row);            
            },
            targets: 'foo'
        }
    ],

    columns: [
        { "title": "Engine", class: 'foo' },
        { "title": "Browser" },
        { "title": "Platform" },
        { "title": "Version", "class": "center" },
        { "title": "Grade", "class": "center" }
    ],

    data: dataSet
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y3fnvzad/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There is no `columns.class` property, use [columns.className](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className) instead.
- You're getting error when changing to `targets:[0]` because your [columnDefs.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) callback doesn't return any data, which it should. Using `targets:0` or `targets:[0]` is a preferred way to refer to a column unless you need to refer using class name by design.
- [columnDefs.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) fires more times than number of cells because this callback function is being called not only for display event but many others (filtering, sorting, etc.).

Your corrected code is:

```
var dataSet = [
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 4.0','Win 95+','4','X'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.0','Win 95+','5','C'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.5','Win 95+','5.5','A'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 6','Win 98+','6','A'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 7','Win XP SP2+','7','A'],
    ['Trident','AOL browser (AOL desktop)','Win XP','6','A']
];

$('#example').dataTable( {

    columnDefs: [
        {
            render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                console.log(type, data, row); 
                return data;
            },
            targets: 0
        }
    ],

    columns: [
        { "title": "Engine", "className": "foo" },
        { "title": "Browser" },
        { "title": "Platform" },
        { "title": "Version", "className": "center" },
        { "title": "Grade", "className": "center" }
    ],

    data: dataSet
});
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3fnvzad/2/) for demonstration.

**Optimized code**

If you don't need to refer to a column by class name, your code could be optimized further. `columnDefs.render` callback could be defined in `columns` property. I have also added type detection in `render` callback to demonstrate how it could be used.

See the code below.

```
var dataSet = [
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 4.0','Win 95+','4','X'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.0','Win 95+','5','C'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.5','Win 95+','5.5','A'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 6','Win 98+','6','A'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 7','Win XP SP2+','7','A'],
    ['Trident','AOL browser (AOL desktop)','Win XP','6','A']
];

$('#example').dataTable( {
    columns: [
        { 
            "title": "Engine", 
            "className": "foo", 
            "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
               // If data is being displayed
               if(type === "display"){
                  return "<b>" + data + "</b>";
               // Otherwise, if data is not being displayed
               } else { 
                  return data;        
               }
          },
        },
        { "title": "Browser" },
        { "title": "Platform" },
        { "title": "Version", "className": "center" },
        { "title": "Grade", "className": "center" }
    ],

    data: dataSet
});
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3fnvzad/4/) for demonstration.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look. However, `columns.class` sets the class name correctly. Also, it's in their own examples. Are you sure it's not valid?

Comment: @Johan, you're right, strangely enough `class` also works. It's not documented though, it's absent in [options reference](https://datatables.net/reference/option/) and [columns.className](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className) pages. I wouldn't rely on that.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you can use the `render` callback on column objects. That's excellent! Thanks a lot for that update. Is there any way to access the row or cell DOM element or jQuery object inside the render callback?

Comment: @Johan, I'm using this to access cell `<td>` element: `$('#example').DataTable().cell(meta.row, meta.col).nodes().to$()`, to access row `<tr>` element: `$('#example').DataTable().row(meta.row).nodes().to$()`. You need `meta` parameter for this which was missing in your original code.

Comment: Aah I see. And if I want to access the current table element, is `meta.settings.nTable` the way to go?

Comment: @Johan, No, I would not rely on `meta.settings`, it's not recommended by authors. Use  `$('#example')`, plain and simple, unless you create your table dynamically.

Comment: I create them dynamically. Any safer option that you know about?

Comment: @Johan, use `var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(meta.settings);` to access API and `api.table().node()` to access the table node. Through API it seems to be safer than reading `settings` object directly.

Comment: If you have time: I'm adding some data to cells in the `render` callback. In your example you're using `if(type === 'display')`. But in order to see my DOM changes I need to do the manipulation in `if(type === 'type')`. What's the correct approach here?